# assign variable from file with string literal newline

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services

This question may sound like a duplicate, but I think it's different than the pages that I've found. I'm trying to assign the contents of a text file to a bash variable, but I want the "\n" character to be included as a string rather than actually seeing it on a new line. For example, the contents of the file look something like this:

> Here is the content of the text file
>
> There are multiple lines
>
> blah blah blah

I want the variable "text_file" below to be assigned the contents of the file so when I use it in my script it looks like so:

> Here is the content of the text file\nThere are multiple lines\nblah blah blah

I'm using this variable in the following script, and I'm getting this error, which I believe is a result of the newline characters in "hello.txt" file that I'm assigning to the variable.

> Error parsing parameter '--message': Invalid JSON: Invalid control character u'\n' at:

```
subject="Test Email Sent Via AWS"
message="here is the message to the user...\n\n"
text_file=`cat hello.txt`
full_message="$message$text_file"

cat <<EOF > generated_message.json
{

   "Subject": {
       "Data": "$subject",
       "Charset": "UTF-8"
   },
   "Body": {
       "Text": {
           "Data": "$full_message",
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       }
    }
}
EOF
aws ses send-email --profile sendmail --from blah@email.com --destination file://destination.json --message file://generated_message.json
```

I think I'm missing something basic, but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily a duplicate question, although it does give me some additional information about what may be causing the issue. So if I'm understanding the responses correctly in that post, you can't have a "\n" character in JSON at all and it needs to be escaped with an additional backslash? If that is the case, does that mean I need to replace all my newline characters in the original "hello.txt" file with "\\n" to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to hobble together valid JSON using traditional Unix tools; use a tool designed for JSON, like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
subject="Test Email Sent Via AWS"
message="here is the message to the user..."

jq -R --slurp \
   --arg message "$message" \
   --arg subject "$subject" '{
       "Subject": {
           "Data": $subject,
           "Charset": "UTF-8"
       },
       "Body": {
           "Text": {
               "Data": ($message + "\n\n" + @text),
               "Charset": "UTF-8"
           }
       }
   }' < hello.txt > generated_message.json
```

`-R` and `--slurp` ensure that the contents of `hello.txt` are passed directly to the `@text` function, which ensures the text is properly quoted as a JSON string. Passing the message and subject as variables, instead of embedding them directly into the filter argument, ensures they are JSON-encoded properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Contents of *text_file*:

```
Here is the content of the text file
There are multiple lines
blah blah blah
```

Expected ouptut

```
Here is the content of the text file\nThere are multiple lines\nblah blah blah
```

You might do

```
declare -a file_as_array
while read line
do
file_as_array+=("${line/%/\\n}")
done<text_file
file_as_text="$(sed 's/\\n /\\n/g' <<<"${file_as_array[@]}")"
unset file_as_array
echo "$file_as_text"
```

**Actual output**

```
Here is the content of the text file\nThere are multiple lines\nblah blah blah\n
```

Comment: What's with the indirection via an array?  Just `file_as_text=$(perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/' text_file)` should get you that.